# EF6.1 DbContext Memory Leak

Tags: c#, entity-framework, memory, memory-leaks

I have a Problem with EF6.1 and DbContext,
I have a very easyly Class, as Database Store for UserSettings/ ApplicationSettings. 
So on every Reload of the Settings, my Memory Grow up. But when I Comment the getItem from DB out, no memory Growing.

```
private SettingItem GetSettingItem(SettingsDbContext context, String appName, String section, Byte scope, String name, String host, Int32? userId, Int32? tenantId)
    {
        IQueryable<SettingItem> items = (from t in context.SettingItem.AsNoTracking()
                                         where t.Enabled
                                         where t.ApplicationName == appName
                                         where t.Section == section
                                         where t.SettingScope == scope
                                         where t.Name == name
                                         where (t.Host == null && host == null) || t.Host == host
                                         where (!t.UserId.HasValue && !userId.HasValue) || t.UserId == userId
                                         where (!t.TenantId.HasValue && !tenantId.HasValue) || t.TenantId == tenantId
                                         select t);

        //return context.SettingItem.FirstOrDefault();
           return items.FirstOrDefault();
    }




    public Object GetSetting(String appName, String section, Byte scope, String name, String host, Int32? userId, Int32? tenantId = null)
    {
        using (SettingsDbContext context = new SettingsDbContext(ConnString))
        {
            SettingItem item = GetSettingItem(context, appName, section, scope, name, host, userId, tenantId);

            if (item == null)
                return null;

            if (item.BinValue != null)
                return item.BinValue.ToArray();

            if (item.StringValue != null)
                return item.StringValue;

            return null;
        }
    }
```

So I have many Tests make,
the GetSettingItem has return null. No Memory Leak
has Return new SettingItem, No Memory Leak,
has return context.SettingItem.FirstOrDefault(), the leak is a little bit lower/slower
the Statement as Lambda is the same Result.

I don't know where is the Problem in this Statement.

For Every Setting who was loaded the Method was Executed Once.
In a Seperate Test, I have get the SettingItem with Ado.Net, and now the increasing Memory is very Slow (100kb in 100 executes). So the Main Leak is not in the SettingsProvider but in the DbContext.

Have someone an Idea to fix it, because to use Ado.Net in an Enviroment with EF is very Dirty.

Kind Regards
Marc

Comment: Why have you decided, that there is memory leak? What tool have you used to detect it? Have you profiled your application?

Comment: How long did you run your tests? Because it can be that the GC only kicks in after some time so maybe after minutes the memory goes down again (or stays put). Or it is related to EF command pooling or caching...

Comment: Did you check the query generated? My guess is that the FirstOrdefault is acting on memory on all filtered elements. Why are you not using Context.Settings.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(t => <conditions>)?

Comment: Hello,

i have it tested first with Task Manager over A time Round 1 Hour. 
Also I have it seen in the Develop Enviroment where the Process was Growing to 20 GB. Then I Comment out the Statement, no Growing. 

Since 24 I Run a seperate Test, the Select was made by Ado.Net, the Method now has the Functionality, but no Growing. 


The Last Tests are with MemoryProfiler from JetBrains.

The Idea from Alexandre, has I Testing, but with the same Result like before. The Table has Only 100 rows, and the Statement returns only One Row, also when I Write SingleOrDefault() it growing also up.